# upload mp4 files to codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, file-upload, mp4

I have to upload different video files on my codeigniter but I couldn't upload mp4 and flv.

I have tried with adding mp4 mime type in config/mimes but in vain.

```
'mp4' => array('video/mp4', 'video/3gpp'),
```

Please let me know the best solution.

Thanks is advance

Comment: Have you tried `$config['allowed_types'] = "mp4";` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$config['allowed_types'] = '*';
```

Comment: write this: `if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
  {
   print_r($this->upload->display_errors());die;

  }` and show me the error you got.

Comment: Error was due to upload_max_filesize , I have increased that and this issue is fixed. Thanks for your cooperation.

Comment: Happie to help buddy :D @user1828822

Comment: @Nil'z your solution is allowed every file for upload,
But i want to upload only image and video files.

Comment: $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png|jpeg|mp4|3gp|avi|mov|wmv|mkv|flv|ogv';

This allowed png, jpg and mov files but mp4 file doesn't support